# how to create an array from json object using jq

Tags: jq

i have a json show below. i using linux with bash and jq. I want this output only using jq.

input json(test.json)

```
{
  "element1":{
   "param1": "element1.value1",
   "param2": "element1.value2"
  },

  "element2":{
   "param1": "element2.value1",
   "param2": "element2.value2"
 }
}
```

i want an expected output like this

Expected output

```
[
{
  "param1": "element1.value1",
  "param2": "element1.value2"
},
{
  "param1": "element2.value1",
  "param2": "element2.value2"
}
]
```

I tried with jq in bash

```
<test.json|jq '.element1,.element2|[{param1:.param1,param2:.param2}]'
```

But it is producing output like this.I mean array is added for every element.

```
[
  {
    "param1": "element1.value1",
    "param2": "element1.value2"
  }
]
[
  {
    "param1": "element2.value1",
    "param2": "element2.value2"
  }
]
```

How to produce the output shown in expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with just two properties from an object, just select the objects to put into an array, then put into an array.

```
[
  .element1, .element2     # select properties element1 then element2
]                          # wrapped in [] creates the array
```

In general, you could use this to gather all values of an object. This should keep the objects in document order.

```
[
  .[]    # select all property values of object (in document order)
]        # wrapped in [] creates the array
```

Comment: Can you please share the jq command, In my code i used <test.json|jq '.element1,.element2|[{param1:.param1,param2:.param2}]' but it give me two array. You can refer to my question for more details.

Comment: `jq '[.[]]' test.json`

Comment: Thanks ,  It worked. One little question. Suppose if i need to do selectively add certain items only?